# Rails associations using Join Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a Movie List app where movies can belong to many lists and lists have many movies. I want to use a join table to associate these List and Movie models. I'm having trouble creating this association in the console.

When attempting this code in console:

```
@bourne = Movie.create(title: "The Bourne Identity")
@list = List.create(name: "Bourne Films")
@list.movies << @bourne
```

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `movies' for #<List:0x007fe2ae380890>
```

Here are my models and schema:

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true

  has_many :list_movies
  has_many :movies, through: :list_movies
end

class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :list_movies
  has_many :lists, through: :list_movies
end

class ListMovie < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

My schema:

```
 create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string "name"
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 end

 create_table "list_movies", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
   t.bigint "list_id", null: false
   t.bigint "movie_id", null: false
 end

create_table "movies", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "title"
  t.string "poster"
  t.integer "year"
  t.integer "runtime"
  t.string "genre"
  t.string "director"
  t.string "plot"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Am I missing something simple? Is this the best way to handle this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is strange..i tried same thing in my console and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange..i tried same thing in my console and it worked perfectly. Also i don't think there's any problem with the associations that you defined. Taking a wild guess..did you try restarting the console? Because if your console was already running and you added any new model then the current console session won't pick it up. You need to restart it or use reload!

Comment: I've reloaded the console and I still get the same NoMethodError.

Comment: If you have modified the existing code then reload! would work. But if you have added new file or something then you need to close the current console session and start the console again.

Answer (score 1):

You're having a bit of trouble with naming conventions,

```
through: :lists_movies
```

suggests Rails to look for a `ListsMovie` model. You called your model `ListMovie` while calling the underlying table `lists_movies`, which again would suggest that the model would be named `ListsMovie`.

You could change your relation to a `has_and_belongs_to_many`, but if you would like to keep the join model, you may simply remove your model to `ListsMovie` (make sure to change the filename accordingly). You may also think of renaming the model, as it is not the most fortunate choice (having the first part pluralized, it does sometimes cause troubles as you have just experienced).

Answer (score 0):

You've named it incorrectly: Rename your model: `ListsMovie`. Note the `s` after the List.

Comment: Shouldn't model names in Rails always be singular?

Comment: It looks at the end of the title, not the beginning. the end is 'Lis....Movie`. The `Movie` is singular. As it should be

Comment: (btw i'd also change the file name as well for consistency.)

Comment: @btcline04 have you reloaded the console?